Force postgres to drop connections on machine shutdown?
I am using Postgres (10) on Ubuntu server (18), and I see that when the Ubuntu server is shutting down, there is a long wait for Postgres to close connections (more than 10mins with estimated time 1h+), so the Postgres wait prevents Ubuntu from restarting.
In fact, since the clients of Postgres are webapps on external cloud, they would never drop connections on their own, and it appears that Postgres will not quit them either (these are only SELECTs though).
This ties in with the observed behaviour that most transactions to Postgres will not be affected by pg_cancel_backend and pg_terminate_backend, and only by killing them via Ubuntu process kill command you can shut down stuck queries.
Anyone has ideas for ensuring proper (as in fast enough) Postgres shutdown when its machine is expected to shut down? I am looking for something that would not require me to manually kill Postgres processes and would work automatically when I ask machine to shutdown normally.
